# How to restart jmx or Mbeann components in Karaf server without getting Insufficient roles/credentials for operation

Tags: java, jmx, apache-karaf, mbeans

Using Mbeans java programming
How to restart jmx or Mbean components in Karaf server without getting Insufficient roles/credentials for operation

Answer (score 0):

In the bin/karaf.sh or bat script, remove the
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.apache.karaf.management.boot.KarafMBeanServerBuilder
JVM argument . The RBAC will be completely disabled for MBeanServer.